# Access remote host via SSH and send command in Python

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to access the remote host using my id and then send the `pbrun` command to switch to root. I have this code so far:

```
import time
import paramiko
output_file = 'paramiko.org'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', port=22, username='test', password='XXXXXXX')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pbrun ohsoap -u root')
time.sleep(0.1

md_output = stdout.read()
print('log printing: ',md_output)

with open(output_file, "w+") as file:
    file.write(str(md_output))
stdin.flush()
print(stdout.readlines())
```

However, after sending the `pbrun` command, it will require a password. How can I provide the password to the running program?

Comment: Use ssh keys to avoid password prompts

Comment: hi mikhail . env does not allow ssh keys for root user

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can help you jumpstart and and get the idea :

```
import time
import paramiko

output_file = 'paramiko_output.txt'
hostname = 'host'
username = 'test'
password = 'XXXXXXX'
command = 'pbrun ohsoap -u root'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, port=22, username=username, password=password)

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.send(command  + '\n')
time.sleep(1)
chan.send(password + '\n')
time.sleep(1)
md_output = chan.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print('log printing:', md_output)

with open(output_file, "w+") as file:
    file.write(md_output)

ssh.close()
```

It would be best if you could use keys for these matters.

Comment: @RandaAhmed Glad to hear it but since It seems you are new to the community, I should mention that we do not thank people via creating new answers. It would be more appropriate to mark one of the answers as accepted answer so that when others visit your question, this would help them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot mohsen . you saved my day as i have done small change and it works fine with me :

```
import time
import paramiko

output_file = 'paramiko_output.txt'
hostname = 'host'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
command = 'pbrun ohsoap -u root'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, port=22, username=username, password=password)
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
time.sleep(3)
chan.send(command + '\n')
time.sleep(3)
chan.send(password + '\n')
time.sleep(3)
chan.send('id' + '\n')
time.sleep(3)
md_output = chan.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print('log printing:', md_output)

with open(output_file, "w+") as file:
file.write(md_output)

 ssh.close()
```